# HTML Get Textbox Value and send to Javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I want it to be so that I have a form, inside which is an input. When the user presses enter in the input, the text inside the input is passed onto a JavaScript functions which creates a pop up alert with the textbox's text.

EDIT: 
What i tried:

```
<div>
<form align="center" method=post>
    <input id="mainText" type="text" name="search" align="center" autofocus="autofocus" onfocus="this.select()" placeholder="Search">

    <input type="submit" onclick=search(); style="position: absolute; left: -9999px"/>
</form>
```

And in my `<head>` I have:

```
function search(){    
    query = document.getElementById('mainText').value;
    window.alert(query)    
}
```

Comment: Added code to question

Comment: <input type="submit" onclick="search()" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px"/>
Check onclick syntax

Comment: Don't name your function `search`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search

Answer (score 2):

**You Need to change your code as below:-**

```
<html>
<body>
<div>
<form align="center" method=post>
    <input id="mainText" type="text" name="search" align="center" autofocus="autofocus" onfocus="this.select()" placeholder="Search">

    <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" style="position: absolute; left: 450px"/>
</form>
</div>
<script>
function myFunction(){
    $a= document.getElementById("mainText").value;
    alert($a);
        }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Either change your button type to simple "button" or put your "search()" in `onSubmit` of the form.

```
<form align="center" method=post>
    <input id="mainText" type="text" name="search" align="center" autofocus="autofocus" onfocus="this.select()" placeholder="Search">

    <input type="button" onclick="javascript:search()" style="position: absolute; left: -9999px"/>
</form>
```

OR

```
 <form align="center" method="post" onSubmit="javascript:search()">
    <input id="mainText" type="text" name="search" align="center" autofocus="autofocus" onfocus="this.select()" placeholder="Search">

    <input type="submit"  style="position: absolute; left: -9999px"/>
</form>

 function search(){

        query = document.getElementById('mainText').value;
        // alert() is bad
        // window.alert(query);
        console.log("Query ", query);
        // This is important, otherwise your form will refresh the page
        return false;
    }
```

From the fact that you try to hide your button, I guess that you want the second solution.

Answer (score -2):

I made that script with JQuery, hope it helps https://jsfiddle.net/cvyzwpy0/

The JQuery code looks like:

```
$(document).on('click', '#send', function(e) {
    var data = $("#yourForm").val();
                    alert(data);
});
```